# How do i get a class member function to have access to another class member function's private member?

Tags: c++

My problem is I am trying to get a class member function to have access to a private member variable of another class. I have declared the class member function as a friend of the class but the compiler continues to tell me that the variable is inaccessible. Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    class Numbers2;

    class Numbers
    {
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        Numbers(){num = 0;};
        friend void Numbers2::getNumbers(Numbers &);

    };

    class Numbers2
    {
    private:

    public:
        void getNumbers(Numbers &);
    };

    void Numbers2::getNumbers(Numbers &numbs)
        {
            cout << numbs.num << endl; //Right here is where the compiler 
                                       //leads me and tells me the variable
        };                             // is inaccessible

    int main()
    {
        Numbers num1;
        Numbers2 num2;

        num2.getNumbers(num1);


        system ("Pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I will truly appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: It is for Numbers2 to declare Numbers as `friend`. Not the other way.

Comment: @Jagannath: You are wrong.

Comment: Can you share *specifically* what the compiler is telling you?  It may benefit you to get better at reading an error message.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Overlooked it. Did not realize that `Numbers2` is using `Numbers` private data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not read *all* the error messages. You only read the one that says the `int` member is inaccessible, but [the messages above it tell you *why*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6412fd8c9def6e02):

```
main.cpp:12:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Numbers2'
         friend void Numbers2::getNumbers(Numbers &);
                                                   ^
main.cpp:4:11: error: forward declaration of 'class Numbers2'
     class Numbers2;
           ^
main.cpp: In member function 'void Numbers2::getNumbers(Numbers&)':
main.cpp:9:13: error: 'int Numbers::num' is private
         int num;
             ^
main.cpp:25:27: error: within this context
             cout << numbs.num << endl;
                           ^
```

Those final errors only show up because the first error caused the entire `friend` declaration to fail. Therefore, it is the first error that you need to fix.

See, you cannot reference `Numbers2::getNumbers` there, because `Numbers2` has only been forward declared at that point: the compiler doesn't know anything about a function within it called `getNumbers`!

Instead, put the definition of `Numbers2` *above* the definition of `Numbers`, and forward-declare `Numbers`.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/459c986fa8c25033))

Comment: Just curious, is it standard to do the Live Demo link now instead of posting the code directly into the answer?

Comment: @merlin2011: In general the code should be in the answer and a demo link provided only as a supplement. In this case I'm still only providing the demo link as a supplement, having opted to provide the solution in prose rather than as code, because the code is quite verbose and the fix is pretty trivial.

Comment: @DonSiege2014, You should accept this answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: Ok I will, this is my first time ever asking a question on here. It says I can accept it in two minutes.